# Prevent a game object from going off the graphics window in Java

Tags: java, graphics, collision-detection

I am building a game in Java that involves the user controlling a ship. Problem is, I do not want the user's ship to go off the screen from both sides while not making the ship moving in a jittery manner.

Here's my code:

```
/* stop the ship if its goes far from the left side 
 * of the graphics window but allow control of
 * the ship if the ship_dx is above 0
 * this applies to the right side of the graphics
 * window
 */

if(ship_dx < 0) {
    // stop the ship 
    ship_velocity = 0;
    ship_dx = 0;
}
else if (ship_dx > 530 ) {
    ship_velocity = 0;
    ship_dx = 530;
} else {
    ship_velocity = 5;
}
```

The ship does not move off the screen but if I force the ship to move beyond the graphics window, the ship looks jittery since I am hard-coding the constants into my ship_dx.

Comment: I don't know why you're setting the `ship_velocity` to `0` then to `5`.  What do you mean by "jittery"?  You usable space really should be a variable (if it's a constant)

Comment: if I do not set the velocity back to 5 the ship does not move because at that point when the ship_dx is 0 or below or above 530, the velocity is still zero. you need to give it the ship some velocity for the ship to move.

Comment: Yes, but why set it to zero at all?  Just saying it looks weird...Why wouldn't you inverse the velocity when it hits the right edge??

Comment: i want the ship to stop moving if the ship attempts to move beyond the graphics window

Comment: The ship doesn't stop moving. Those three assignments (velocity=0, dx=1, velocity=5) are executed right after each other, before any other code (like the one drawing the ship) runs. It seems you have some fundamental misconceptions about how your code works.

Comment: should it be `ship_velocity = -5` when ship_dx > 530 and i think you mean ship.x instead of ship_dx which is the change in velocity.

Comment: dx seems right. delta x is change in x which is change in position not velocity

Comment: @Nicholas Think about it you set `ship_velocity` to `0`, then you set `ship_dx` to something, then you set `ship_velocity` to `5`...exactly WHEN does `ship_velocity` get evaluated?  Unless you're doing some really weird threading, it's less then likely that the evaluation of `ship_velocity` is going to occur before the second assignment - personally, it's just a waste...

Comment: @Nicholas I'd suggest the `dx` is HOW MUCH the x position is to be changed by - but I'm happy to be wrong...

Comment: that what I wrote. ship_dx is change in position of the ship. I fixed my code. with everyone's contribution, I fixed the code! upvotes!

Comment: Just a note.. use constant or variables instead some 'magic' numbers (like the 530 and other).. will save you a lot of time when you'll want to change some values..

Comment: If you know then answer, than post it like an answer and close the question..